# Mailgun not verify with Name.com after 48 hours

Tags: dns, mailgun

I am working on Rails app.
So i need to create email verification system.
On production i decided to use Mailgun as my email service.
After i purchase my domain i tried to set it up with Mailgun but it seem didn't workout

My mailgun account didn't verify after 48 that i already update DNS following their instruction.

So many people suggest that i should add @ as hostname for first record but
i can't add it, always

```
The Record Host field is invalid.
```

like in the picture below

[image]

How can i fix this? 
Thanks!

Comment: I think they mean, as CNAME. * -> @

Comment: @MrMichael you mean Type CNAME?

Answer (score 0):

name.com say leave the host blank so remove the @ and try putting the definition in quotes

> "v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all"

Once that's done use [Google's dig tool](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/) to check the DNS record.

Comment: It might help with debugging if you said what domain you were trying to setup?